# What does the Invalidate Caches/Restart do in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have seen many answers suggest that one should Invalid Caches/Restart in order to improve the performance of Android Studio, whether it's memory or CPU. It also can be used to set up correct themes. I was wondering what it actually does though, since it seems to be the solution to so many problems.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Android Studio makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete them. This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files, so clearing caches will clear the old cache and make Android Studio faster.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html?origin=old_help

Comment: sometimes it is the only way to fix a problem for which you're banging your head against a wall until you don't realize it's not your fault but the darn IDE's.

Comment: @DevUt The whole purpose of cache is to make any system faster. Then how can clearing a cache speed up Android Studio?

Comment: @DevUt what kind of files ?  Gradle  or its own something that is used only by android studio?

Comment: You can find an explanation/example from this video: https://youtu.be/ctyoO6bZgjo

Answer (score 10):

**Invalidate Cache** **clears project structure related information (only) cached by Android studio**. 
Please note that this cache is different from "Build Cache" and "Gradle cache" briefly explained below.

**Build Cache -** stores certain outputs that the Android plugin for Gradle generates when building your project e.g. unpackaged AARs and pre-dexed remote dependencies. Build cache is enabled by default in recent plugins (2.3.0+).

**Build Cache path:** *C:\Users\[User_Name]\.android\build-cache\gradleVersion*

Here version value is driven by value defined in build.gradle file in your project.
e.g. *classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion"*
Invalidate Cache has no impact on Build Cache. It can be cleared using "gradlew cleanBuildCache" command instead.

**Gradle Cache** - maintains Download Dependencies.

**Gradle Cache path:**
    *C:\Users[user_name]\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1*  [Windows]
    *~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1*                      [Mac]

Also, as mentioned by @anurag, Clean Project has no relation to Build Cache.

More @ https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache

Comment: That documentation does not back up your statement that "Invalidate Cache is to clear 'Build Cache' ". Where did you read that?

Comment: Hi @tir38, thanks for pointing out, i explored further and it turned out that I was mistaken in above statement, just updated the content above. Please let me know if any further comments, consider upvoting if you agree :)

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Going to Build > Clean Project will only delete the local build files present in the app module and in the project. It has nothing to do with the cache.